# Using wp_dropdown_page() to display a dropdown of a custom post type

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with the list of a certain post type.
I saw that I could use the wp_dropdown_pages function to do that.
I added this code inside my td but when the page displays the code is not interpreted. The are only few examples to look at.

```
<td><?php wp_dropdown_pages(array('id'=>'marque0','post_type' => 'Brands')); ?></td>
```

additionally I need to filter a second dropdown list which contains only child post of the parent selected in the first dropdown. To do that I need the id of the parent post. How can I get this from the element selected in the first dropdown list ?

Thanks a lot.

Update :

I found a way to go around the usage of PHP inside the wordpress page, I created shortcodes to call the wp_dropdown_pages, then I use the shortcodes inside my page.

Comment: Your `post_type` of `Brands` is invalid because it contains a capital letter. Try it with `brands` (and double-check that that is the same as what you declared in your `register_post_type` call.)

Comment: Hi, you're right, I looked at the table wp_posts to see the actual custom post type name and filled the right value but the code still appear uninterpreted.

Comment: I think I know why. It looks like to be impossible to use php code directly into a wordpress post/page, I,m looking for a solution

Comment: Yes this is it, php is not interpreted inside wordpress page/post, you must install a plugin a define you own shortcode to call a php function within the page/post.

Comment: Do not add php code into any type of editor. It creates loop holes that can be exploited by hackers

Comment: Hi Pieter, Thanks for your warning, what do you suggest to workaround this ?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly enough (!), just specify in your custom post type's settings `'hierarchical' => true`, not the `hierarchical` argument in [wp_dropdown_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) function.

```
register_post_type( 'brands', array(
    'labels'    => array(
        ..........
    ),
    .........
    'hierarchical' => true,
    .........
));
```

Then it should work:

```
wp_dropdown_pages(array(
   'id' => 'marque0',
   ..........
   'post_type' => 'brands'
));
```